# proper way to handle common header files with C and Git

Tags: c, git

So i have folders like this

```
c:\projects\generic\
c:\projects\project1\
c:\projects\project2\
```

Each folder under projects are their own separate local git repository. A project may use one or more header files from the generic folder. If a project uses a header file, it needs to be right in the project folder, not a subfolder under the project folder. Also, I probably wouldn't want the latest and greatest, I'd want to pull it by tag so I could be sure I have a specific version of the file in use for that project.

How would I do that? Is this something that could be done with submodules? Is there a better way to organize the folders in this situation?

Comment: Don't use a version control system as a package management tool.  If two projects each depend on a header, then you should have 3 separate projects.   One for each project, and one for the library that provides the header.  Each project deserves its own git repository.  Modularity is a good thing.  Integration is bad.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd want [...] a specific version of the file in use for that project.

Yup: submodules are for exactly that. A submodule is a nested repository, the using projects' commits record (only) exactly which (other) commit SHA they need checked out at the submodule's path, `git submodule` just does the chores of getting the right submodule commits checked out when you want.

> If a project uses a header file [from another repository], it needs to be right in the project folder, not a subfolder under the project folder [... I'm on windows].

It's lucky these are headers, otherwise there'd be a problem with that combination. As it is, the compiler can chase the relative pathnames with a `#include "relative/path/to/submodule/header.h"`:

```
repo
|--generic.h:  "#include generic1/generic.h"
|--generic1
   |--generic.h:  the real thing
```

Comment: That won't work. With git I've tagged genericX.h at various points, and I may need to use the version tagged as "v1.0" today, and then "v2.0" at some later date. I'm on windows currently so symlinks are out anyway.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  Better now?